# How to add custom theme to tailwind css besides dark and ligth

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

I want to add a reader mode which is different from light and dark for example

```
<div class="text-white dark:text-black reader:text-yellow-100"><div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider [creating a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) that adds a new variant called `reader` that modifies a selector for when it should apply. For example, if `reader:` should apply when a parent element has a `reader` class:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('reader', '.reader &');
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="text-white dark:text-black reader:text-yellow-100">Foo</div>

<div class="reader">
  <div class="text-white dark:text-black reader:text-yellow-100">Foo</div>
<div>

<div class="dark">
  <div class="text-white dark:text-black reader:text-yellow-100">Foo</div>
<div>
```